# Pagination not showing results on next page

Tags: php

Looking for some help please. I am using the following code to filter and show results which works fine.  My problem is the results aren't passing on to the second page  so the page becomes blank no errors. very new to this so all help is welcome.

```
$num_rec_per_page=2;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("searchresults") or die("ERROR");

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) exit();

$vars = array('companyname','location');
$verified = TRUE;
foreach ($vars as $v) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$v]) || empty($_POST[$v])) {
       $verified = FALSE;
    }
}
if (!$verified) {
    echo "Sorry no results found, please enter your search";
    exit();
}

// isset function is also used in checking for the existence of data in $_POST
if (isset($_POST["companyname"]) && $_POST["companyname"] != '') {
    $companyname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["companyname"]);
    $companyname = " AND (companyname LIKE '%$companyname%')";
}
if (isset($_POST["location"]) && $_POST["location"] != '') {
    $location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["location"]);
    $location = " AND (location LIKE '%$location%')";
}

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };

$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page;

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM reviewsandtips WHERE member_id > 0". $companyname . $location . "LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";

$sql_result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

// now echo the code for the table heading
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reviewsandtips WHERE member_id > 0". $companyname . $location;
    $sql_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
    $total_records = mysql_num_rows($sql_result); //count number of records
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page);

    echo "<a href='codetest.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
        echo "<a href='codetest.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
    }
    echo "<a href='codetest.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page

} else {
    echo '<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not the cure to prevent mysql injection. Use prepared statements. And.. dont use the mysql library, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: try [this](http://www.onlinetuting.com/pagination-in-php-mysqli/) once.

Comment: Thanks guys for the info will make the changes and see where I get to.